# org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out:

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am trying to index a large set of log files obtained from a tomcat server. I have written the code to open each file, create an index for each line and then store each line using Apache lucene. All of this is done using multi-threading.

I get the this exception when i try to this code

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out:
```

Code

```
  if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE)
        {
          // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
           System.out.println("adding " + path);

                indexWriter.addDocument(doc);

       } else {
          // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so 
       // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact 
           // path, if present:
            System.out.println("updating " + path);

                indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", path), doc);

          }
        indexWriter.commit();
        indexWriter.close();
```

Now I thought since i am committing the index every time, it might cause a write lock. so i removed `indexWriter.commit();`:

```
if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE)
    {
      // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
       System.out.println("adding " + path);

            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);

   } else {
      // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so 
   // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact 
       // path, if present:
        System.out.println("updating " + path);

            indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", path), doc);

      }

    indexWriter.close();
```

Now i get no exception

**Q. So my question is why indexWriter.commit(); causes the exception. And even if I remove indexWriter.commit(); i do not get any problem while searching. That is I get the exact result I intended to have. Then why to use indexWriter.commit(); ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it is similar to the DB commit, unless you commit the transactions, the document add to Solr are just held in Memory. Only on commit would the Document be persisted in the index.
If the Solr crashes when the documents are in memory, you may lose these documents.

[Explanation](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3a-optimize-is-bad-for-you) :-

> One of the principles in Lucene since day one is the write-once
>   policy. We never write a file twice. When you add a document via
>   IndexWriter it gets indexed into the memory and once we have reached a
>   certain threshold (max buffered documents or RAM buffer size) we write
>   all the documents from the main memory to disk; you can find out more
>   about this here and here. Writing documents to disk produces an entire
>   new index called a segment. Now, when you index a bunch of documents
>   or you run incremental indexing in production here you can see the
>   number of segments changing frequently.  However, **once you call commit
>   Lucene flushes its entire RAM buffer into segments, syncs them and
>   writes pointers to all segments belonging to this commit into the
>   SEGMENTS file**.

If the document already exists in Solr, it would just be overwritten (determined by the unique id).
Hence your search may still work fine, but the latest document is not available for search unless you commit.

Also, once you open and indexwriter it would obtain a lock on the index and you should close the writer to have the lock released.